# Pipe size selection for seawater circulation system

Tags: pipelines, water-pressure

I am trying to get the right pipe size for seawater circulation system aboard a ship.  The water is used to keep oysters alive while transporting them.

The system has 8 Ebara SQPB 100 pumps.  The output of each pump is theoretically 1.2 m<sup>3</sup> per minute, 4” outlet pipe, and very little head— maybe 1-2 meters.  And no suction head-- the pumps are at or below the waterline.

The inlet is be from a sea chest, that feeds one large pipe that branches off into 4” pipe to each pump.

How larger should the main inlet pipe be?

[image]

Comment: have you considered a water aeration system

Comment: How is the output an area and not a volume?

Comment: Size the intake based on the max output of the pumps ie 1.3 * 8. that would be the maximum condition, then consider the max allowable speed in the intake - what would be a relevant maximum?

Comment: I agree with Solar Mike's suggestion. The other consideration that would be critical is how much suction lift the pumps can provide if they are self-priming during the initial start-up. It may be beneficial to upsize from the max flow basis calculation to ensure priming at the lowest sea chest liquid level (if that varies).